# Generate Elcipse Project Files for Gazebo - Indexing causes GC to Crash Eclipse

Tags: cmake

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to use the Eclipse generator for CMake to make some project files for Gazebo, but it whenever it tries to index the files it crashes with an out-of-memory exception.

Has anyone else had any luck with this?

I have gotten it working by just importing the code as an "Existing Makefile Project" in CDT, but things aren't strongly linked together.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/795/generate-elcipse-project-files-for-gazebo---indexing-causes-gc-to-crash-eclipse/) by [eacousineau](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/120/eacousineau/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 27 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-01-24**:
I'm having the same issue, and [here](http://wiki.opencog.org/w/Using_Eclipse_CDT) is what I found: "Works well with Ubuntu 12.04, Eclipse 3.7.2 and OpenJDK 6b24. Known to have memory/GC problems with Ubuntu 12.10. Eclipse 3.8.0 and Oracle/Sun JDK 7". So I'm going to try to downgrade the Eclipse ver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I can confirm the problem for Ubuntu 12.10, Eclipse 3.8 (see my comment above).

Luckily everything works fine with latest release - [Eclipse 4.2 (Juno)](http://www.eclipse.org/juno/).

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) with karma: 330 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0